# What does "synchronization actions are totally ordered" mean?

Tags: java, multithreading, happens-before

I am reading *Java Concurrency in Practice*, in "16.1.3 The Java Memory Model in 500 words or less", it says:

> The Java Memory Model is specified in terms of actions, which include reads and writes to variables, locks and unlocks of monitors, and starting and joining with threads. **The JMM defines a *partial ordering* called happens-before on all actions within the program.** To guarantee that the thread executing action B can see the results of action A (whether or not A and B occur in different threads), there must be a happens-before relationship between A and B. In the absence of a happens-before ordering between two operations, the JVM is free to reorder them as it pleases.
>
> **Even though actions are only partially ordered, synchronization actions—lock acquisition and release, and reads and writes of volatile variables—are *totally ordered*.** This makes it sensible to describe happens-before in terms of “subsequent” lock acquisitions and reads of volatile variables.

About "partial ordering", I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19126835/5232255) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213443/instruction-reordering-happens-before-relationship-in-java#comment23983255_16629365), but I don't quite understand *"Even though actions are only partially ordered, synchronization actions—lock acquisition and release, and reads and writes of volatile variables—are totally ordered."*. **What does *"synchronization actions are totally ordered"* mean?**

Comment: Partial ordering, A must precede B: `ACDB`. Total ordering: `ABCD`

Comment: @Michael l still don't understand what is the relationship between *synchronization actions* and *total ordering*, counld you give an example?

Comment: Did you read the rest of the chapter? I can't remember the specifics of the content but it seems like you are stating that you don't understand what is deliberately a tl;dr summary without having read the 16 subsequent pages of explanation.

Comment: The exact synchronization actions are listed in the question. JVM can't reorder them - they have to be executed in the exact other that is in your code. What exactly don't you understand here?

Comment: @Michael No, I haven't, I will read the reset.

Comment: @Amongalen My question is *"What does synchronization actions are totally ordered mean?*".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Analyzing the statement "synchronization actions are totally ordered":

- "synchronization actions" is a set `S` of program operations (actions)
- we have a relation `R` over set `S` : it is the happens-before relation. That is, given program statements `a` and `b`, `aRb` if and only if `a` happens-before `b`.

Then what the statement says, is "relation `R` is **total** over S".

---

"relation `R` is total over `S`", means that for every two operations `a,b` from set `S`  (with `a!=b`), either `aRb`, or `bRa`. That is, either `a` happens-before `b`, or `b` happens-before `a`.

---

If we define the set `S` as the set of all lock acquisitions and lock releases performed on the same lock object `X`; then the set `S` is **totally** ordered by the happens-before relation: let be `a` the acquisition of lock `X` performed by thread `T1`, and `b` the lock acquisition performed by thread `T2`. Then either `a` happens-before `b` (in case T1 acquires the lock first. T1 will need to release the lock first, then T2 will be able to acquire it); or `b` happens-before `a` (in case T2 acquires the lock first).

---

Note: not all relations are total.

In example, the relation `<=` is total over the real numbers. That is, for every pair `a,b` of real numbers, it is true that either `a<=b` or `b<=a`. The total order here means that given **any** two items, we can always decide which comes first wrt. the given relation.

But the relation `P`: "is an ancestor of", is not a total relation over the set of all humans. Of course, for some pairs of humans `a,b` it is true that either `aPb` (`a` is an ancestor of `b`),  or `bPa` (`b` is an ancestor of `a`). But for most of them, neither `aPb` nor `bPa` is true; that is, we can't use the relation to decide which item comes "first" (in genealogical terms).

Back to program statements, the happens-before relation `R` is obviously partial, over the set of **all** program statements (like in the "ancestor-of" example): given un-synchronized actions `a,b` (any operations performed by different threads, in absence of proper synchronization), neither `aRb` nor `bRa` holds.